# the user created in the admin panel cannot log in to the admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-4.1

I have a custom user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ACCESS_LEVELS = (
        ('user', 'Авторизованный пользователь'),
        ('admin', 'Администратор')
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='Эл. почта'
    )
    access_level = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        choices=ACCESS_LEVELS,
        blank=True,
        default='user',
        verbose_name='Уровень доступа',
    )

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.is_superuser or self.access_level == 'admin'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'email: {self.email}, '
            f'access_level: {self.access_level}'
        )
```

Registered in the admin panel:

```
@admin.register(CustomUser)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'access_level')
    search_fields = ('email', 'access_level')
    list_filter = ('email',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.is_admin:
            obj.is_staff = True
        obj.save()
```

When I create a superuser or a user with staff status and try to log in, a message appears:
`Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`

So I Googled the issue and tried everything I could. Here are all the problems I investigated:

**Database not synced:** I synced it and nothing changed.

**No django_session table:** I checked; it's there.

**Problematic settings:** I just added the created apps to INSTALLED_APPS.

**User not configured correctly:** is_staff, is_superuser, and is_active are all True.

**Old sessions:** I checked the django_session table and it's empty.

**Missing or wrong URL pattern:** Currently I have url('admin/', admin.site.urls) in mysite/urls.py.

**Wrong server command:** I'm using python manage.py runserver.

**Something wrong with database:** I tried deleting the database and then reapplying the migrations, but nothing changed.

Comment: What you're seeing in your `password` field (at admin or DB)?

Comment: how did you create the superuser. with admin panel, or with django shell or with any other method ?

Comment: @JPG in the password field I see an unencrypted password

Comment: @AbhijithK everything works when I create a superuser using `python manage.py createsuperuser`, the problem occurs when I create through the admin panel

Comment: in the admin panel,when you enter the password directly, it will not be hashed. When you try to login, It will be checked against database value  and hashed password value from the form . They both will not be equal

Comment: @AbhijithK And how can I hash the password when creating a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`UserAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2848e5d0ce5cf3c31fe87525536093b21d570f69/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L44)<sup>[Django-GitHub]</sup> to register UserModel. It will provide the functionality to hash the password when you enter the password in admin panel so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```